# Unittest button onClickListener inside code

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

So, I am being new in testing and I would like to test that my callback listener is being fired, when a user clicks on a button.

code:

```
    private View.OnClickListener continueButtonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        callbackListener.startDownload(checkBox.isChecked());
    }
};



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
 ....
 Button continueButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.continueButton);
 continueButton.setOnClickListener(continueButtonClickListener);
....
}
```

Unittest:

```
@Test
public void testContinueButtonClick() {
    continueButton.performClick();
    verify(mockedCallbackListener).startDownload(anyBoolean());
}
```

error:

> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Can someone tell me, who can I test that callbackListener.startDownload() is being called for sure?

Comment: I think you need to move `verify(mockedCallbackListener).startDownload(anyBoolean());` before `continueButton.performClick();`.

Comment: I am not sure why, could you explain me? I want to test, if the button is clicked then the code inside executes. For this I have to call the performClick first, I guess

Comment: Usually you first setup your expected outcome when mock object is called and then do the actual call. Otherwise when `continueButton.performClick();` is called the mock does not know what to method calls to expect on `mockedCallbackListener`.